# data handshake between flask-socketio and d3

Tags: d3.js, flask-socketio

I'm wokring on real-time app using flasks-socketio(server) and d3.js(client) as part of my research proj, and struggling hard to perform the data handshake between server and clinet and it's not working and new to websockets. Kindly help me with the data sharing methods using flask-io and d3, Thank you.

Screenshot of the output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUGMe.png)

If I assign the data values in client side, can able to read from server side, but if i assign the data in server side, client is not able to read it. why ?

Server-code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
import json, os
import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET KEY'] = 'help!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
port = int(os.getenv('VCAP_APP_PORT', 2021))

# df = pd.read_csv("stocks.csv", usecols=['Symbol','Name','Sector','Price'])
# stocks = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
# print(stocks.head())


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('demo.html')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/app')
def connect():
    emit('check_connection', {'data': 'Connected'})

@socketio.on('sum', namespace='/app')
def sum(data):
    result = data['numbers'][0] + data['numbers'][1]
    # emit('sum_result', {'result': result})
    return {'result': result}


@socketio.on('stocks', namespace='/app')
def send_data():
    df = pd.read_csv("stocks.csv", usecols=['Symbol','Name','Sector','Price'])
    data = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
    # print(df.head())
    emit ('stock_data', {'stock_data': data}, broadcast=True)


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/app')
def disconnect():
    print('Clinet disconnected!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=port)


client_code: 

        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

const sio = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/app');

        sio.on('check_connection', function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            sio.emit('sum', {numbers: [1, 2]}, (result) => {
                console.log(result);
            });
        });
        
        sio.on('stock_data', (data) => {
            const stockData = data;
            console.log(stockData);
        });

        sio.on('disconnect', function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        });
</script>


    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCNs9.png
```

[Final Output screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUGMe.png)

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: I didn't get any errors. Cannot able see my data in the console, so am trying to understand if the server side code is correct or not.? Also, could you please guide me, how to call the data from server to client side. I have followed your videos on YT(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUh3-65PIAE&list=PLCuWRxjbgFnPZTBMYbz9UNGvTLNggRMjb&index=7) to understand the logic. thank you

Comment: Miguel, I'm trying to assign the data values in server side and calling it in client side, that process is not working. not sure why ? :(

Comment: Sorry, but you are not providing enough information. The screenshot shows messages that you are getting in your console that are not in the code you included. You need to be more specific regarding what exactly you expect to happen and what happens instead of that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, could you please confirm if my server abs client code are correctly written to call for custom data handshake between server and client.

Comment: I can only the see the output for the data connection and sum values, not for the chart data. Also, if you see the server code I have assigned a stock data in server and when I try to call it in client it’s not working. Could you please have a look at the code abs let me know if am missing any thing. Thank you graph_data
   // socket.on('chart_data', function(data){
     //   console.log(data);
    //});

Comment: I'm sorry but it is impossible for me to evaluate your code. Too confusing. Your Python indentation is messed up. In the client you are assigning something to socket.on, and this does not make any sense to me. Provide a complete and runnable example and I'll test it, otherwise, I don't think I can help.

Comment: Sure I’ll update the running code and share it accordingly. Thanks again Miguel

Comment: Miguel, I have updated the working code of my work, please let me know assist with the process of Flask-socketio data handshake works. Thank you

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to get assistance on? Your screenshot shows that the client is receiving the answer from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, my issue is that I can able to receive the output for connection and sum value but not for 'stock_data'  which i have assigned the custom data event for the client side and am not sure if the client is recognising my event or not, so could you please assist me on this and below is the ref: sio.on('stock_data', (data) => {
            const stockData = data;
            console.log(stockData);
        });

Comment: The server sends the `stock_data` event in the `send_data()` function, which handles the `stocks` event from the client. But your client isn't emitting the `stocks` event, as far as I can see.

Comment: I’ll try to pass the stocks as my event in client and check for the results but in the video you mentioned that whichever the emitting event name we passed in server that should be same event name passed in the client right? Correct me If I’m wrong , thanks again Miguel

Comment: Thanks a ton Miguel, it worked and can able to access the stocks data now and I have attached the screenshot for the same.